# create mp4 slide show on raspbian

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, omxplayer

I have RPi running raspbian.
I want a solution to convert a folder of image files to an mp4 slide show video that can be played with omxplayer.
I did it with ffmpeg and following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate .1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

It works with mpv media player but playing it with the flowing command with omx player does not do anything.

```
omxplayer --loop --no-osd --win 0,0,128,224 --orientation 90 out.mp4
```

I must use omx player to output on exact window and be compatible with older programs.
Not sure what would be the right way to do this. I have already a node js server running on Pi that I can use if needed.
Thanks

Comment: Add `-r 5` after the input and check.

Comment: -r Does not do it. I think the output is missing fps metadata.

Comment: Share full command you tried and its log.

Comment: ffmpeg -y -framerate .1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -r 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4

Comment: [swscaler @ 0x1f28250] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x1e69c10] using SAR=1/1
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 5 fps, 10240 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      46kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=3861387.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=8 speed=0.000268x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I should have force both input and output rates(r .2 and -r 30)
Here is my final command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r .2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'  -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -crf 18 -b-pyramid none -acodec ac3 -ab 1536k -scodec copy -r 30 out.mp4
```

Thank you Gyan for your comments.

Comment: Input `-r` is not required. Difference will be due to value of output `-r`. Depends on your player's caching policy.

Comment: Actually it is required to control the time of each slide. but the right argument is -framerate not -r. so I modified the command to : sudo ffmpeg  -y -framerate .11 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -r 10  -c:v libx264  -vf scale=128:224   Org1.mp4

Comment: Yes, but not for generating playback friendly files on your platform.

Comment: Since I do not need to use play back, this is fine for me. But if I remove the -framrate then the video will be too short how can I control each slide time?